# Proving that Char of a field is 2.

Tags: ring-theory

Let F be a field of order $2^{n}$. Prove that Char(F)=2.

I'm stuck with this question after 30 mins and I have to move on.

Note that by a certain theorem, this field has characteristic prime.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: My intuition tells me I need to relate the order of the field to the element then relate to Lagrange's theorem.@Ennar

Comment: Yes, Lagrange's Th tells you that the additive order of 1 must be a factor of $2^n$. So the characteristic divides $2^n$. If you use your theorem you are done. Proving that theorem is not difficult (hint: a field has no zero divisors).

Comment: One approach (probably not the quickest) would be to first prove that the characteristic of any field is prime or 0, then note that the order of any element is a divisor of the order of the group and apply that to the additive group of the field.

Comment: @almagest I do not understand the part where you mention additive order of 1 must be a factor of 2^{n}. If the order of a field F =$2^{n}$, then every element a in F has order $2^{n}$?

Comment: @Mathematicing A field with $2^n$ elements is an additive group with $2^n$ elements and 1 is a member.

Comment: But there are many other members. Why do we single out 1? I recall that $2^{n}$=n.2=2+...+2=0$

Comment: Solutions would be good. Will return back to the question at a later time. I do not think it is a good idea to persist in a question for hours with a tired mind.

Comment: $2^n \neq 2n$ tho

Answer (score 1):

Definition: let $F$ be a field.  The *characteristic* of $F$ is the smallest number of times $1$ must be added to itself to get $0$.  Equivalently, the characteristic of $F$ is the smallest number of times any nonzero element of $F$ must be added to itself to get $0$.

Let $(G, \cdot)$ be a finite group with $s$ elements.  If $x \in G$, the smallest positive integer $t$ such that $x^t = e_G$ is called the *order* of $x$ in $G$.  Here $e_G$ is the identity element of $G$.  Lagrange's theorem says that $t$ divides $s$.

Now let $F$ be a field with $2^n$ elements.  Then $F$ is a group with respect to addition.  Let $x = 1$.  The order of $x$ in $F$ is the same thing as the characteristic of $F$.  Let $t$ be the order of $x$.  By Lagrange's theorem, the order of $t$ divides $2^n$.

But the positive divisors of $2^n$ are just $1, 2, 2^2, ... , 2^{n-1},2^n$.  Since you know the characteristic of $F$ is a prime number, there is only one possibility here.

Comment: I solved it earlier on but without using Lagrange's Thm. Thanks for your solution though.
I used the theorem: 
1) The characteristic of a field is either 0 or prime p.
2) Let F be a finite field of characteristic prime p. Then, the order of the finite field F is $p^{n}$ for all positive n.

Comment: Your second step is the wrong implication. That assumes that you know the characteristic and tells you the order. You are trying to show the opposite direction.

Comment: I think OP is correct in what he just said: if you assume (1) and (2), you can successfully prove the characteristic of a field $F$ with $2^n$ elements is $2$.  If $F$ had characteristic $0$, it would be infinite, and if $F$ had prime characteristic $p \neq 2$, it would have $p^k$ elements for some $k \geq 1$, also impossible.  So the only possibility is $\textrm{Char } F = 2$.